# Issues with Scaling horizontally with Cassandra NoSQL

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am trying to configure and benchmark my AWS EC2 instances for Cassandra distributions with Datstax Community Edition. I'm working with 1 cluster so far, and I'm having issues with the horizontal scaling.

I'm running `cassandra-stress` tool to stress the nodes and I'm not seeing the horizontal scaling. My command is run under an EC2 instance that is on the same network as the nodes but not on the node (ie i'm not using one of the node to launch the command)

I have inputted the following:

`cassandra-stress write n=1000000 cl=one -mode native cql3 -schema keyspace="keyspace1" -pop seq=1..1000000 -node ip1,ip2`

I started with 2 nodes, and then 3, and then 6. But the numbers don't tell me what Cassandra is suppose to do: more nodes to a cluster should speed up read/write.

```
Results:    2 Nodes: 1M 3 Nodes: 1M 3 Nodes: 2M 6 Nodes: 1M 6 Nodes: 2M 6 Nodes: 6M 6 Nodes: 10M
op rate                 6858    6049    6804    7711    7257    7531    8081
partition rate              6858    6049    6804    7711    7257    7531    8081
row rate                    6858    6049    6804    7711    7257    7531    8081
latency mean                29.1    33  29.3    25.9    27.5    26.5    24.7
latency median              24.9    32.1    24  22.6    23.1    21.8    21.5
latency 95th percentile     57.9    73.3    62  50  56.2    52.1    40.2
latency 99th percentile     76  92.2    77.4    65.3    69.1    61.8    46.4
latency 99.9th percentile   87  103.4   83.5    76.2    75.7    64.9    48.1
latency max                 561.1   587.1   1075    503.1   521.7   1662.3  590.3
total gc count              0   0   0   0   0   0   0
total gc mb                 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
total gc time (s)           0   0   0   0   0   0   0
avg gc time(ms)             NAN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
stdev gc time(ms)           0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Total operation time        0:02:25 0:02:45 0:04:53 0:02:09 00:04.35    0:13:16 0:20:37
```

Each with the default keyspace1 that was provided.
I've tested at 3 Nodes: 1M, 2M iteration. 6 Nodes I've tried 1M,2M, 6M, and 10M. As I increased Iteration I'm marginally increasing the OP Rate.

Am I doing something wrong or do I have Cassandra backward. Right now RF = 1 as I don't want to insert latency for replications. I Just want to see in the longterm the horizontal scaling which I'm not seeing it.

Help?

Comment: Have you tried adding threads or even instances of stress? It may be that you're not able to generate enough throughput. Is your node utilization high? A couple of minutes of `dstat -rvn 10` should tell you

Comment: @phact according to the tool its running at 200 threads. As far as utilization goes only the `cassandra-stress` tool is hitting the node. Can you elaborate on instances of stress? is that like running more than one cassandra-stress at once?

Comment: My question was, is cassandra-stress generating enough writes to really utilize your cluster? Play with different number of  threads and see if there's an impact. Look at the OS resources of all your machines to see if there's a bottleneck. Yes I do mean more than one stress at once.

Comment: @phact it is on auto - so at 200 threads 1M i have the above numbers. Im running new tests with 12 nodes, and its terrible. at 4 threads im getting 2K/s OP rate at 400 threads im getting 7.9K Op rate. Is there something that I have miss configured that would make these statistics like this?

Comment: Client threads should usually match the number of cores on your client machine to avoid excessive context switching. Why are you saying its terrible? We're you expecting op rate to be 100x for 400 threads vs. 4? Maybe that would work on a machine with 400 cores.

Comment: I bet your cassandra-stress machine is starved for cores and at 100% cpu utilization when running.

Comment: So find the bottleneck, fix it and repeat.

Comment: @phact what are the numbers that I am looking at between Node vs Instance in order to determine bottleneck please?

Comment: You are looking for OS subsystem saturation. If it's disk, you would see IO Wait creeping up. If it's CPU, you'll see CPU utilization increase and eventually pegged cores. If it's network, you'll see network traffic plateau.  This may happen on your client (stress) node or it may happen on your cassandra nodes. In your case, stress is not saturating c* so you probably need a beefier stress box or more machines running stress.